# JSON Parsing ERROR in WSO2 EI Outlook Connector

Tags: javascript, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am trying to do some simple script which actually concat multiple values in which json Object also included by using WSO2 EI 6.5.0.

Incomingpayload:

```
{"Company":"Grupo Bimbo DSDE","Description":"Test SR","Priority":"P4Low","Short Description":"Test SR","Ticket Type ":"Service Request","Configuration Item":""}
```

WSO2 Script Mediator:

```
    <script language="js"><![CDATA[var log = mc.getServiceLog(); 
  log.info("Logging inside Script Mediator");  
var testTicketNo=mc.getProperty("DummyTicketNo");  
var Incomingpayload=mc.getProperty("Incomingpayload");  
 //log.info("Incomingpayload::" + Incomingpayload);  
    
    var emailcontent="Hi Team<br/><br/> The requested Ticket Creation Done.. and the Created Ticker No is: " + testTicketNo + "<br/><br/> Below is the request Data for your reference...<br/><br/>" + JSON.parse(Incomingpayload)+ "<br/> Let us know if you have any queries.. <br/><br/>Cheers<br/> WSO2 Team";
//log.info("emailcontent is==" + String(emailcontent));
mc.setProperty('content',emailcontent.toString());]]></script>
```

Output for above script :

```
 Hi Team<br/><br/> The requested Ticket Creation Done.. and the Created Ticker No is: TestSR2506005<br/><br/> Below is the request Data for your reference...<br/><br/>{"Company":"Grupo Bimbo DSDE","Description":"Test SR","Priority":"P4Low","Short Description":"Test SR","Ticket Type ":"Service Request","Configuration Item":""}<br/> Let us know if you have any queries.. <br/><br/>Cheers<br/> WSO2 Team
```

I am using this above content to send Email by using [WSO2 Outlook connector](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/esb-connector-outlookmail/blob/master/src/main/resources/messages/sendMail.xml).

In above predefined connector, JSON Structure look like below.

```
{
                "Message":
                {
                    "ToRecipients":$1,
                    "Body":
                        {
                            "ContentType": "$2",
                            "Content": "$3"
                        }
                }
            }
```

Finally i am using this concatenated String content in $3. above predefined payload doesn't accept my STRING Content($3 is the place where concatenated String will come automatically), I hope placing String with Json will lead to problem here.

ERROR:

```
[2021-07-13 15:16:20,596] [] ERROR - ScriptMediator The script engine returned an error executing the inlined js script function mediate
com.sun.phobos.script.util.ExtendedScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped com.sun.phobos.script.util.ExtendedScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: missing } after property list (<Unknown source>#1) in <Unknown source> at line number 1 (<Unknown Source>#27) in <Unknown Source> at line number 27
        at com.sun.phobos.script.javascript.RhinoCompiledScript.eval(RhinoCompiledScript.java:68)
```

If I correct this JSON Parsing, Email will be send successfully.

Is there any tip to escape this JsonObject in String Content?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `JSON.stringify(payload)` to escape double-quotes in the JSON Object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can't put non-escaped `"` (quotes) inside another JSON in wso2. TryInstead of using:`JSON.parse(Incomingpayload)`, just `+Incomingpayload+` or `+Incomingpayload.toString()+`that should generate JSON with escaped quotes.

As alternative, you can also try `+JSON.stringify(Incomingpayload)+`, but that will only work with:

```
<script language="nashornJs">
```